# Open a popup window on a hfref click from Backend c# code

Tags: c#, radgrid

I am trying to open a popup window from backend c# code on an ahref.  [image: Open the Popup]

As you can see, this is done  on a datatable row

```
    foreach(LinkCustomerFile lcf in linkedCustomerFiles)
    {
     var readLinkType = ecfsc.GetLinkType(lcf.LinkType.LinkTypeId,DateTime.Now,Page.User.Identity.Name);
           dt.Rows.Add("7","45",readLinkType,string.Format("<a href='../LinkCustomerFiles.aspx?action={0}&customerFileId={1}&referenceNumber={2}&linkcustId={3}' target='popup'>{0} </a>  ","Remove",lcf.CustomerFile.CustomerFileId,lcf.RefCustomerFile.CustomerFileId,lcf.LinkCustomerFileId));
   }
    RadGridLink.DataSource=dt;
    RadGridLink.DataBind();
```

Is there a way to achieve the popup window from this code when ever user click **Remove**

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor addition in your code.

**1st)** Just add the JavaScript code on OnClick attribute of a tag directly.

```
@foreach(LinkCustomerFile lcf in linkedCustomerFiles)
            {
            var readLinkType = ecfsc.GetLinkType(lcf.LinkType.LinkTypeId,DateTime.Now,Page.User.Identity.Name);
            dt.Rows.Add("7","45",readLinkType,string.Format("<a href='../LinkCustomerFiles.aspx?action={0}&customerFileId={1}&referenceNumber={2}&linkcustId={3}' target='popup' onclick='return confirm('Are you sure you want to Logout?')'>{0} </a>  ","Remove",lcf.CustomerFile.CustomerFileId,lcf.RefCustomerFile.CustomerFileId,lcf.LinkCustomerFileId));
            }
            RadGridLink.DataSource=dt;
            RadGridLink.DataBind();
```

**2nd)** Another way is to add the Javascript code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   return confirm('Are you sure you want to Logout?')
}
</script>
```

Then call the function in your code directly:

```
@foreach(LinkCustomerFile lcf in linkedCustomerFiles)
            {
            var readLinkType = ecfsc.GetLinkType(lcf.LinkType.LinkTypeId,DateTime.Now,Page.User.Identity.Name);
            dt.Rows.Add("7","45",readLinkType,string.Format("<a href='../LinkCustomerFiles.aspx?action={0}&customerFileId={1}&referenceNumber={2}&linkcustId={3}' target='popup' onclick='myFunction()'>{0} </a>  ","Remove",lcf.CustomerFile.CustomerFileId,lcf.RefCustomerFile.CustomerFileId,lcf.LinkCustomerFileId));
            }
            RadGridLink.DataSource=dt;
            RadGridLink.DataBind();
```